# Vent in closet below stairs

Tags: ventilation, closet

I'm preparing this small closet below stairs to use as storage.

[image pending]

Should I drill a couple of small vent registers in one of the stair risers to reduce moisture and stale air inside? Right now, when the door is closed, there's no air movement, except for small openings such as under the door, but minimal.

Comment: Is it in the basement?  Is it get damp because one or more walls are concrete or the floor?  In that case yes, you'll need ventilation and perhaps air movement.  Otherwise a closet shouldn't necessarily need venting.

Comment: No, first floor

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you plan on storing there.

I have lots of closets that have no air movement and they are just fine.

I wouldn't worry about it.